# What does "The MIT License – Clarity on Using Stack Overflow Code" mean for RPSE?

Tags: discussion

How does [the quoted question/answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271080/the-mit-license-clarity-on-using-stack-overflow-code?cb=1) change affect our Raspberry Pi community? I am a little unclear on "Stack Overflow" vs. "Stack Exchange" for starters.  Do I need to worry about requesting others use attribution for code **I** provide as well as ensuring I attribute stuff I use.

EDIT: Ah, I got confused when the post seems to refer specifically to Stack Overflow but was on the Meta Meta Site or should that be Stack Exchange Meta<sup>2</sup>  (the one for ALL Stack Exchange communities) - it was migrated from Stack Overflow Meta.  That being the case - that it is a communities-wide change - perhaps this post will raise awareness for RPSE users... 8-)

Comment: If you scroll down the comments far enough you'll find the OP says that while he is not sure ("confusing for us in the company also") it should be regarded as "network wide proposal".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as Stack Overflow vs Stack Exchange, Stack Exchange is the network, and Stack Overflow is a specific site under that network.  Raspberry Pi, Unix and Linux, World Building, etc are all apart of the Stack Exchange network.

To quote the blog:

> **What about other sites in the Stack Exchange network?**
>
> These terms will go into effect for all code posted after Jan. 1 on
>   all sites in the Stack Exchange network.

The tl;dr of the blog post is that you need to give proper attribution to any code you provide that is not your own. If you pulled it from a blog, you need to name the blog and link back to it.  If it is your own code, you are releasing it under the MIT license.

Comment: I have no idea what this means to those of us who post our code as Public Domain.  Does it mean we can no longer post our code?  I doubt if I'd bother to post original code if I was forced to use a restrictive licence.

Comment: @joan: The MIT License is very open: https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT.  That's just a part of doing business on this network.  Not a lot we can do about it.

Comment: After trawling through the discussion my best guess is that my Public Domain stuff will remain Public Domain.  The user will have the option of using the site MIT licence or my Public Domain unlicence (and therefore  any or no licence terms as they choose).

Comment: Would you be able to tell us which blog you are talking about? If you're talking about [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271080/the-mit-license-clarity-on-using-code-on-stack-overflow-and-stack-exchange?cb=1) post on Meta.SE, which is a *meta* post, your answer fundamentally wrong. **Nothing is being released under the MIT license yet. All posts and code are still released under CC-BY-SA 3.0**

Comment: As for the changes **taking place Feb 1st 2016**: New code contributions will be licensed under a modified MIT license. Existing code and all non-code contributions will still be licensed under CC-BY-SA 3.0

Comment: The meta post says that the modifications to the MIT license will be: `Contributors agree to give code users permission to ignore the MIT License’s notice preservation requirement, as long as users give reasonable attribution upon request of the copyright holder (or Stack Exchange on behalf of the contributor).` In other words, you won't need to attribute for new contributions, unless asked by the author or SE.